# Confused about bluetooth and WiFi drivers for my Dell notebook

Tags: windows-8.1, bluetooth, dell-inspiron, wifi-driver

I'm quite confused what I need to install on my Notebook - It's a Dell Inspiron 17R SE 7720 but I think that doesn't matter much - the exact model number.

It's just a general question, what drivers I need to install.

I would ask on the Dell forums except my previous questions still have gotten no response.

So hopefully someone here can explain.

I installed Windows 8.1

but I would like to install drivers.. even though my wifi works with the default windows drivers, my bluetooth keyboard doesn't. I think this will be resolved when I install drivers from the Dell site.

But I'm confused because there are so many:

Intel Wireless 6250/6150 WiMAX Application < I think this is not necessary to install, I have no wimax

Dell Wireless 1703/1901 Wi-Fi + BT DriverDell Wireless 1704 802.11b/g/n (2.4GHz), BT 4.0+HS Driver

Intel 2230/6235 Wi-Fi + BT v4.0 + HS Adapter Driver

Do I really need to install all of the last 3 drivers?

I especially don't understand the different between the last 2.

Can anyone shed some light? thanks.

I did have the bluetooth keyboard working but with quirks on windows 8 (quirks meaning taking minutes to connect after notebook wakes up from sleep)

on Windows 8 I also had a problem with the wifi drivers (can't remember which, I uninstalled them all when I ran windows 8) causing intermittent dropout often.. really making wifi unusable.

But maybe on windows 8.1 everything will work fine if I install it all, however I would prefer to try just the minimum required (but probably minimum required for bluetooth 4.0 as well)

I really don't understand if the bluetooth 4.0 drivers update all versions of bluetooth.. or they are specifically only supporting bluetooth devices that connect at bluetooth v4 level.

Here is the dell drivers page, just in case anyone needs it http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/inspiron-17r-se-7720/drivers

Comment: Press the Windows 8 Start button (to get MetroUI) -> type `compmgmt.msc` -> you should get a result (possible under "settings") -> click `compmgmt.msc` to open your computer management console window -> Click `Device Manager` from left -> You should have an "Unknown device" whcih will probably be your BlueTooth adapter -> Right click the device and click "Properties" -> Go to the "Details" tab -> Select "Hardware Ids" from the dropdown menu -> You'll see some info appear -> Right click the top line and click "Copy" -> Paste the result here so we can identify exactly what device it is...

Comment: Whilst you're on the `compmgmt.msc` screen - tell us what your WiFi adapter is - this will give us (and you!) a clue as to which drivers package you should download, as it appears the drivers for WiFi and BlueTooth are packaged together so if you get the right WiFi card then the BlueTooth drivers should be the right ones...

Comment: well, there are no unknown devices - windows 8.1 seems to be pretty good at recognizing and installing some standard drivers. Hmm, looks like I even have the 4.0 bluetooth installed.

Comment: Intel Centrino Wirless Bluetooth 4.0 + High Speed Adapter
USB\VID_8087&PID_07DA&REV_7869
USB\VID_8087&PID_07DA

Comment: Intel Centrino Wirelesss-N 2230
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0887&SUBSYS_44628086&REV_C4
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0887&SUBSYS_44628086
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0887&CC_028000
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0887&CC_0280

Comment: note, I didn't install any drivers from the Dell page.. these are all win8.1 installed. Overall I'm happy with WiFi so don't see any need to change that, but I don't understand why my bluetooth keyboard gives a hadware error (I mean windows says something like that) when it tries to connect after I type in the pin code on the keyboard. However, I know it works on my other windows computer (windows 8) and also worked before on this notebook under windows 8 (but probably only after the dell drivers were installed)... however I'm not sure about that.